# Reading text file values

Tags: c

I've got the below code and am trying to read a text file which is comma delimited and need to grab the values.
The text file (out.txt) contains 2 numbers:

```
12.4,45.8
```

My code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    system("python Grab_Values.py > out.txt");

    FILE *ptr_file;
    char buf[1000];
    int v1;
    int v2;

    ptr_file =fopen("out.txt","r");
    if (!ptr_file)
            return 1;
    while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
            fscanf(buf, "%d,%d\n", &v1, &v2);

    fclose(ptr_file);
    printf("%d" "\n", v1);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling I get the following errors:

```
test.c: In function âmainâ:
test.c:17:10: warning: passing argument 1 of âfscanfâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/stdio.h:445:12: note: expected âstruct FILE * __restrict__â but argument is of type âchar *â
```

I am still a c noob so its probably a simple error but I can't figure out what :(

Comment: `int fscanf ( FILE * stream, const char * format, ... );` Also, using `%d` to read a float value (12.4) is not correct.

Comment: definition of fscanf: `int fscanf ( FILE * stream, const char * format, ... );`

Comment: You appear to be reading in integers ("%d,%d"), but the values you show are floating point values.

Comment: @SouravGhosh wow 4 second faster

Comment: Use `sscanf` instead.

Comment: Change `fscanf` to `sscanf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things are wrong with this one:

```
while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
        fscanf(buf, "%d,%d\n", &v1, &v2);
```

1. `fgets` already reads data, so it's not longer available for `fscanf`
2. you use `%d` as format specifier (integer), but you want to read float values (also change the type of `v1` and `v2` !)
3. The first argument of `fscanf` is the file stream, so you need to provide `ptr_file` there.

So change it to:

```
fscanf(ptr_file, "%f,%f", &v1, &v2);
```

But also note, that this text format might not work with other locales, where the comma is the decimal point! You should consider enclosing comma separated float values by quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks - thats pointed me in the right direction. Seem to be getting further now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using 'fscanf', which is used to read from a file. I think you want to use 'sscanf' to read the input from the 'buf' char array you read the file content into.

Bonus points - you could actually just use fscanf and do away with the 'fgets'.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the code is here,

```
fscanf(buf, "%d,%d\n", &v1, &v2);
```

`fscanf()` expects a `FILE*`, or more clearly a `stream` but you are giving a character pointer..

You can use `sscanf()` instead, if you wanna read from character pointer